# Move files that have the same name but different extension

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use the script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426411/6215518) to move avi files I've converted into mp4, back into their original folders. All seems to work ok, the script tries to move the files to the correct location (see below) but the mp4 files aren't moved.

> What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: Z:\AVI\MVI_4965.mp4 Destination: Z:\Pictures\2011\04_21_11_Bergen\MVI_4965.mp4".

All files are located on my Z: NAS drive and I've modified the script to account for this (see below) starting from `PS Z:\>`.

```
# Create a hashtable with key = file basename and value = containing directory
$mediaFiles = @{}
Get-ChildItem -Recurse .\Pictures | ?{!$_.PsIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {
  $mediaFiles[$_.BaseName] = $_.DirectoryName
}

# Look through lost files and if the lost file exists in the hash, then move it
Get-ChildItem -Recurse .\AVI | ?{!$_.PsIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {
  if ($mediaFiles.ContainsKey($_.BaseName)) {
    Move-Item -whatif $_.FullName $mediaFiles[$_.BaseName]
  }
}
```

Any ideas whats stopping the files being moved or how to correct?

Answer (score 3):

That's the point of `-WhatIf`. It simply says what it would do without actually doing it so you can verify the script first. Remove it from the `Move-Item` command.

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks, I'm pretty much a newb to anything powershell!

Comment: Glad i could help. Remember to mark the chosen answer using the button on the left side so the question will be closed as answered. :-) Welcome to SO